# States returned from custom hook undfined

Tags: reactjs

State returned from   custom hook is undefined. Why  is  it undefined I do not understand, in the form below I am trying to get states from the custom useInput hook but they are undefined, what is the problem here?

> Custom hook

import {useState}  from 'react';

```
export default function useInput (checkValidity){
 const [value,setValue] =  useState('');
 const[isTouched,setIstouched]= useState(false);
 let  isThisInValid = !checkValidity(value) && isTouched;

 var  changeValidity = (event)=>{
 setValue(event.target.value); 
 }

 var submitTheValue = (event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
        setIstouched(true);
 }
 
return {
    isThisInValid :isThisInValid,
    changeValidity:changeValidity,
    submitTheValue:submitTheValue,
```

}

}

> Form in which i am trying to get value from custom hook

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '../Button/Button.js'
import {useState,useRef} from 'react'
import Style from '../Input.module.css'
import useInput from '../hooks/useInput'



 function BasicInput (props){

 const {validityofInput,       //trying to get state from custom hook
       changeInputValidity,
       submitTheValue, 
       }
       = useInput((value) => value.trim()=='');

const {validityofEmail,
       changeEmailValidity,
       submitTheSecondValue, 
  } 
  
  = useInput((value) => value.includes('@'));



  
console.log(validityofEmail)   //undefined
console.log(validityofInput)  //undefined

  return  <>

   <form className = {Style.form}
    onSubmit = {submitTheValue}
    noValidate
   >
     <div>Name</div>
      <input
       id="input"
       className = { validityofInput && Style.wrong}
       onChange = {
       changeInputValidity
}/>

     <div>Email</div>
       <input
        type = "email"
        id="input"
        className = {validityofEmail && Style.wrong}
        onChange = {
        changeEmailValidity
}/>

<Button  name = "CLICK ME"> </Button>
     </form>
    </>

   }
    export default BasicInput;
```

Comment: What's that, is it a joke??

Comment: I wanted to edit my post, but i  had deleted it, so I had to undelete in order to edit

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object in the hook with these properties:

```
return {
    isThisInValid :isThisInValid,
    changeValidity:changeValidity,
    submitTheValue:submitTheValue,
}
```

and you are destructing from the hook these properties:

```
 const {validityofInput,      // notice here it must be "isThisInValid"
       changeInputValidity, // and here must be  "changeValidity"
       submitTheValue, 
       }
```

You can rename the properties like this if you want:

```
 const {isThisInValid: validityofInput,      
       changeValidity:changeInputValidity,
       submitTheValue, 
       }
```